# So significant serial mediating effect, but there is a significant mediating effect when the individual mediators are explored?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, partial-least-squares

The statistical analysis used was PLS-SEM using WarpPLS.I have four variables, with 1 IV (W), 1 DV (Z), and 2 mediators (X and Y)

I was able to find that when run through **W -> X -> Y -> Z** the serial mediation was not significant.

I tried to see if different paths may be significant, so I analyzed 1.) **W -> X -> Y** and 2.) **X->Y->Z**. The results for these 2 paths are now significant.

I am having a hard time making sense of these results, and any input or suggestions are highly appreciated